# Read webm video from blob on firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video, blob, webrtc

I'm testing WebRTC API. More precisely the webcam part.

So I read the W3C draft and used it in firefox to record myself from a webpage. It works (not as good as expected, but it does). I mean that I can download a video formated as webm that is readable by my computer.

I want to previsualize my video before sending it to the server. So I madethis code:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
video.innerHTML = '<source src="' + url + '" type="video/webm"></source>';
video.play();
```

This does'nt work at all. I got just a blank element on my webpage...

Any suggestion to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an issue of Firefox. With e.data we get a blob but we have to redefine a new blob to make it work:

```
var new_blob = new Blob([e.data], { type: e.data.type });
```

Notice that for now (2014-09-30) firefox does not support officialy the video encoding and the specification is in draft that is not validated by the W3C.

Comment: Today the bug still unresolved. Your solution works for me in FF 42.0a2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the proble is I do  not understand the what is the object you get in e.data, also you can check if the mime is correct `console.log(e.data);;console.log(e.data.type);` , what are the output of these,

also have you tried this, [firefox webm capture](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/AudioVideo-on-Firefox.html), they show preview of the video.

Comment: The mime type is ok (I have it on the blob at e.data.type as you suggest). Thanks for the script, i'm going to check how he's doing.